# wixproj/msbuild program creating automatically unwanted folder in the solution tree

Tags: msbuild, wix, windows-installer

I want to remove folder from my deployment folder.
I'm using removedir task.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FolderToExcludefromDeploymentFolder Include="$(SourceDir)\Support" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <RemoveDir Condition="Exists('$(sourceDir)\Support')" Directories="@(FolderToExcludefromDeploymentFolder)" />
</Target>
```

In that case i get a folder in the solution tree.

[image: Solution tree]

In case of trying to delete the folder i get this error and the itemgroup element will automatically will be removed.

[image: Error message]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could fix this issue is to move all problematic properties to BeforeBuild target and set them as DefineConstants.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <SourceDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)..\..\..\Example</SourceDi>
  <FolderToExclude>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)..\..\..\Example\Support</FolderToExclude>
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);SourceDir=$(SourceDir);FolderToExclude=$(FolderToExclude)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<RemoveDir Condition="Exists('$(sourceDir)\Support')" Directories="@(FolderToExclude)" />
</Target>
```

This solution worked for me but didn't find the reason behind this.